# How to diff through two different collections?

Tags: php, laravel

So my process is this,

API call to a json file, retrieve that data that looks something like this: (let's call this API call)

```
    [
      {
        "id": 5123
        "title": "Title 1",
        "sizeOnDisk": 2040422598,
        "status": "released",
        "website": "",
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 6123
        "title": "Title 2",
        "sizeOnDisk": 2040422598,
        "status": "released",
        "website": "",
        ...
      },
      {
        "id": 7123
        "title": "Title 3",
        "sizeOnDisk": 2040422598,
        "status": "released",
        "website": "",
        ...
      },

    ]
```

Now, after I get that data, I grab all the data from a database table, which looks something like this:

```
| id |  title  | api_id |
------------------------
| 10 | Title 1 |  5123  |
| 12 | Title 3 |  7123  |
```

Now if you notice, I am missing Title 2 from the api in the database. I'm trying to return the missing items from the api that are not in the database.

As of right now, I've figure out how to return the IDs of the missing items like this:

```
$api = new Api();
$remoteIds = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents($api->url('movie'))))->pluck('id');
$localIds = Movie::all()->pluck('radarr_id');
$diff = $remoteIds->diff($localIds)->flatten();
return $diff;
```

... but I need to return the entire row. If I remove the `->pluck('id')`, I get a `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` error..

So how could I return the entire data of the missing item from the api? I understand I can do a `array_intersect_key` but the keys are different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **filter** instead of **diff**.

```
$api = new Api();

$remoteIds = collect(json_decode(file_get_contents($api->url('movie'))));

$movies = Movie::all()->pluck('id')->values();

$diff = $remoteIds->filter(function($item) use ($movies) {
    return in_array($item->id, $movies);
});

return $diff; // Get the list of objects, not only ids
```

Comment: Thank you so much! First thing, you code right off the bat wasn't working. I had to make two edits. First and most important, I was receiving this error: `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given` so I just changed `$movies` (in the filter return, which was an object) to `$movies->toArray()`. The next thing I had to do was change something that is only relative to me. My database has the api id's under a different column, so I just changed `$movies = Movie::all()->pluck('id')->values()` to `$movies = Movie::all()->pluck('api_id')->values();`

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: I was aware of filter, just didn't know how to input the function variables. Again, you're a life saver.

Comment: Another thing to add is that I had to do `!in_array(...)` to find the items that I was missing.